# How to get Katalon cmd to print in ADO Pipeline triggered powershell prompt

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, katalon-studio

I am trying to finish my pipeline for testing in ADO.

I have my pipeline set so a PowerShell script will run the command from build cmd in katalon (katalon -noSplash -runMode=console etc etc)

However, when Powershell executes that command it runs the Katalon cmd prompt in a new window, which messes up the pipeline process and won't pass/fail.

Is there a way to place the results from the Katalon cmd prompt to the PowerShell script or has anyone found an alternate solution for ado results?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `-consoleLog` switch, as well as the `-runMode=console` part, for example:

```
katalon -noSplash -runMode=console etc...  -consoleLog
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work via Console code exit status.

This is the guide I used to figure it out https://forum.katalon.com/t/console-mode-and-returning-exit-status/9469/6